# Should I put functions in highest class or lowest class

Tags: java, methods

Say I have a class called Document.
In the Document class, there is a Text attribute.

**Document.java**

```
public class Document {
     private Text text = new Text();
}
```

Lets say the Text class looks something like this:

**Text.java**

```
public class Text {
     // it doesn't matter what this method does.
     public void refresh() {...}
}
```

If I wanted to refresh the text in the document from another class, should add a getter to the Document class, like this:

**Document.java**

```
public class Document {
     private Text text = new Text();
     
     public Text getText() {
          return text;
     }
}
```

And refresh the text by doing:

```
new Document().getText().refresh();
```

Or is it better to do this:

```
public class Document {
     private Text text = new Text();
     
     public void refreshText() {
          text.refresh();
     }
}
```

And refresh the text by doing:

```
new Document().refreshText();
```

Which one is better to do?

I assume it depends on the situation, but in more complex examples, if I were to do the first method, my code would end up looking like:

```
new Document().getFrame().getPanel().getTextBox().getText().refresh();
```

compared to the second method in which my code would look like:

```
new Document().refreshText();
```

I'm just not sure which one is more "right", thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's largely a matter of taste/personal opinion. However, the first option (partially) exposes the internal implementation of `Document` (by telling us that it contains a `Text`) and of `Text` (by telling us that it contains a `refresh()` method), and violates the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

If you don't care about exposing internal implementation details and possibly breaking through the separation of layers and concerns in your code, you can just chain method calls like in your first example. But if you care, you should opt for the second approach. Beware, though, that with that approach, you risk bloating your classes with wrapper methods that call the methods of other classes. Either way you should design your classes carefully, and refactor if/as needed.